# Как защитить In-App Purchases от Jailbreak в xCode

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

```
Сразу хочу сказать, что подобной темы нет не в гугле, не в HashCode, поэтому название темы прошу не менять, она очень актуальна.
```

**И так**, дорогие iOS девелоперы, расскажите как можно бороться и сопротивляться с Jailbreak'ом?
Как избежать потерь средств, если наши встроенные покупки стоят и нам денег (приложения)?

Поделитесь своими способами защиты, ведь такие твики как: "LocallAPStore" и "iAPFree" с легкостью ломают встроенные покупки.

Comment: Никак. Джейлбрейкнутое устройство находится под контролем пользователя, а не приложения. Считайте это частью риска при разработке.

Answer (score 1):

не запускайтесь вообще на взломанных устройствах. [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530364/how-to-detect-that-the-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-device) пример как это делать

Answer (score 0):

пользователи с jailbreak это не та категория, которая покупает

Comment: http://readwrite.com/2013/02/08/12-really-good-reasons-to-jailbreak-ios-6#awesm=~owR5k0Z4ELpLjZ чего-то я не наблюдаю там "использовать пиратский софт и никогда больше не платить"

Comment: Ну вот я и спрашиваю, как уберечь программу от JailBreak'a? Например в Сбербанк Онлайн вообще не входит, если на устройстве стоит джейл.

Comment: ejcto, программы для iOS - http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showforum=140 , кстати, там и моя программа среди всех.. Уже 7000 скачиваний с сайта, а ведь программа стоит 99 руб в AppStore..

Comment: Поднимаю вопрос, помогите добрые люди

Comment: @SuperPonchik, если вашу програму пиратят - надо радоваться, значит вы написали не совсем уж ненужное никому.

Comment: @eicto ну то что оно не ненужное это мне прибыль с неё говорит, но хотелось бы увеличить прибыль закрыв доступ взломанным устройствам, у меня есть расширение в программе, которое мне обходится в 40 рублей, а в приложении оно стоит 129 рублей, но взломанные устройства ставят расширение бесплатно, через твики, тем самым вводят меня в минуса.. Вот я и хочу узнать как другие разработчики сделали распознавание взлома..

Comment: @SuperPonchik с точки зрения "сделал продукт - продал, кому захотел и как захотел" вы, конечно, в минусе. Но сейчас и в разработке, и в музыке принуждение к оплате начинает играть противоположную роль. Вы можете получить больше за счет меньшей, но более лояльно настроенной аудитории, не говоря уже о нематериальных бонусах за сохранение собственного лица. Хотя пираты - это тоже ваша аудитория, и за счет этого она также ширится.